# Capture dot notation property values ignoring random characters at the start and end

Tags: regex

Hi I have the following string:

```
'TD#{test1.test.test3234.rsatars.23432i.rstrsti.arstarst}'
```

Is there a way with regex to strip out the stings so I get the following:

```
'test1.test.test3234.rsatars.23432i.rstrsti.arstarst'
```

What I have so far is just capturing the '.' character, can't figure out how to get the whole property path string.

```
[\w]\.[\w+]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\w+\.[\w.]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n71lu2/1)

The `\w+\.[\w.]*` pattern will match 1 or more word chars, then a dot and then 0 or more word or dot chars.

Or, alternatively

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)+
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/n71lu2/2).

The `\w+(?:\.\w+)+` pattern matches 1+ word chars, and then 1 or more repetitions of a dot followed with 1+ word chars.